# How can I configure GNOME so that it searches EXIF data?

Tags: gnome, search, tracker

I would like to be able to search all my images metadata when searching via Nautilus or Activities. So far I have not been able to do anything more than search image file names.

I know that GNOME uses [tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/GettingStarted) to index files and run the integrated search. But when I search for a tag I've added to an image file, that file is not returned as a result. Either when searching via Nautilus, Activities, or on the command line.

I tried `tracker search -i Road` and received no results.

If I run `tracker info imagename.jpg`, a little ways down the returned list is:

```
'nao:hasTag' = 'urn:tag:Road'
```

I also tried using dconf-editor to browse the settings, as suggested in the documentation for tracker. I did not see any settings that jumped out as helpful. Maybe I just missed something?

System info:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"

$ tracker --version
Tracker 2.0.3

This program is free software and comes without any warranty.
It is licensed under version 2 or later of the General Public License which can be viewed at:

  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.2
```